# bash: extract only the part of the string following the dot

Tags: bash, string

Say I have a string such as

```
="/home/Rob/.SpaceVim"
```

and I want to extract the string following the dot. How do I do this?

I know `$` is also used to represent the last character, and `\` can be used to make character in string literal. So I've tried stuff like `awk '\.$'` but not had any success.

Comment: Where do you have this string? In a file, or in a shell variable, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

```
echo "/home/Rob/.SpaceVim" | grep -o "\..*$"
```

or

```
echo "/home/Rob/.SpaceVim" | sed 's;[^.]*;;'
```

---

Without dot and GNU `grep`

```
echo "/home/Rob/.SpaceVim" | grep -Po "(?<=\.).*$"
```

or `sed`

```
echo "/home/Rob/.SpaceVim" | sed 's;^.*\.;;'
```

you could even include `cut`

```
echo "/home/Rob/.SpaceVim" | cut -d'.' -f2-
```

(beware you'll see variations in behaviour among those for lines that contain no dot or more than one dot, but you've not specified what to do in that case).

Comment: Wonderful!...Now I need to figure out how they work :-| (there was also another solution: echo "${a##*/}" ) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @1toneboy I suggest to start with the basics of [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), [sed](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and avobe all, [regular expressions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html), which are used in most text manipulation commands.

Comment: This has been my 'year of linux'; about six months ago I was getting into learning BASH (vim etc.) then due to home demands halted learning. I did to basic awk, grep, sed etc. but I've forgotten the specifics. I remember reading wiki about Regex lol. But yeah, I need to delve back in to really get my head around what's going on. Cheers

Comment: I meant *above :)

Comment: I did some BASH research today which was a nice refresher. However, I still can't understand how grep -o "\..*$" AND  grep -Po "(?<=\.).*$" work. Also, I know nothing about Perl. For the first one why is there an escape operator then dot \. that's particularly confusing to me. I understand . is single character, wildcard and $ is position after last character in string; but Can you please shed any insight/explanation? Thanks!

Comment: @1toneboy Let's take this: 1) `echo "a.b" | grep -o ".*$"` and 2) `echo "a.b" | grep -o "\..*$"`. The first one matches *all characters* (`.`) till the end. The second one matches from *literal dot* (`\.`) to the end. The results then are: 1) `a.b` 2) `.b`. Does this help?

Comment: @1toneboy *"I still can't understand how grep -o "\..*$" AND grep -Po "(?<=\.).*$" work"*: you can check [this guide (lookbehind)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot; okay, great explanation! It does help, thanks! As for the Regex, I am realising I have a LOT to learn, thanks for the resource.

Answer (score -2):

Read `man bash`.

```
a="/home/Rob/.SpaceVim"
echo ${a##.*/}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `echo "${a##*/}"`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Probably more `printf '%s\n' "${a##*.}"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OP referenced in a comment, now deleted, that he wanted (though not very clearly) the output both with dot and without it. I had in mind the former when I did this comment and  my answer.